# Tkinter crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

After running my program it crashes because overload, I heard you cna fix this with using threading problem I don't really understand how it Works and how I could use it . This program basicly runs server list on GUI then suproces should check if servers are online if not sent email. All information saved in json files. So basicly when this program starts subprocess it just "not responding". You can find full code https://github.com/aurimasjank/Pinger-Alpha/blob/master/Pinger_Alpha.py

```
class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
    self.tk = Tk()
    self.Firstgo=True
    self.timespend = 0
    self.tk.wm_title("Web Service")
    self.tk.configure(background='black')
    #self.tk.wm_state('zoomed')
    self.tk.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
    #Frames
    self.tk.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.tk.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.left= Frame(self.tk, bg="black")
    self.left.grid(column=0, row = 0, pady=5 ,padx=10, sticky=N)

    self.center = Separator(self.tk, orient="vertical")
    self.center.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns")

    sty = Style(self.center)
    sty.configure("TSeparator", background="#00CC00")

    self.right= Frame(self.tk, bg="black")
    self.right.grid(column=2, row = 0, pady=5,padx=10, sticky=N)

    self.probar= Frame(self.tk, bg= "black")
    self.probar.grid(column=1, row = 1, sticky= S)

    self.botFrame = Frame(self.tk, bg="black")
    self.botFrame.grid(column=2, row = 1, pady=5, sticky= S)

    self.colnr = 0
    self.rownrleft = 0
    self.rownrright = 0

    self.statuslabel = Label(self.botFrame, text="Script status :  ", bg="black",fg="#00CC00", font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.statuslabel.grid(column=0, row = 0)

    self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.probar,orient ="horizontal",length = 410, mode ="determinate")
    self.progress.grid(column=0, row = 0,pady= (20,0))

    self.string = StringVar()
    self.timecount = StringVar()


    self.titlelbl3= Label(self.probar, textvariable= self.string ,bg="black", fg="#00CC00",font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.titlelbl3.grid(column=0, row = 1)

    self.statuscount1 = Label(self.botFrame, text="Pinger last run in :",fg="#00CC00", bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.statuscount1.grid(column=0, row = 0)

    self.statuscount = Label(self.botFrame, textvariable=self.timecount,fg="#00CC00", bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.statuscount.grid(column=0, row = 1)




    self.tk.after(1000, self.task)
    self.label = {}
    self.statuscount = 0
    self.freezecheck = 0


def task(self):

    i = 0
    self.list=[]
    self.probarcount=0
    self.string.set (str(self.probarcount) + " / " +str(len(self.list)*10))
    self.progress["value"] = self.probarcount

    self.progress["maximum"] = len(self.list)*10
    self.right

    self.list = openfile()
    name=""
    if self.label != {}:#deleting previous information that we could refresh
        for ele in self.label:

            self.label[ele].destroy()
    self.label= {}
    whatframe = self.right
    whatrow= self.rownrright
    self.list = sorted(self.list, key=itemgetter('status'))
    for elem in self.list:#creating visual status if server is online text is in color green and opsite red

        if "_VPN" in elem["name"]:
            whatframe = self.left
            whatrow= self.rownrleft
            name=elem["name"][:-4]
            self.rownrleft+=1


        else :
            whatframe = self.right
            whatrow= self.rownrright
            self.rownrright+=1
            name=elem["name"]
        if elem["status"]=="true":
            lb = Label(whatframe,text=name , fg="#00CC00",bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 28))
        if elem["status"]=="false":
            lb = Label(whatframe,text=name, fg="black",bg="#00CC00", font=("Helvetica", 28))
        lb.grid(column= 0, row = whatrow ,pady=10 , sticky= W+E)    

        self.label[elem["name"]] = lb


    self.wd=self.tk.winfo_reqwidth()
    self.wdd=self.tk.winfo_width()

    self.fwidth = self.wdd/5
    self.left.columnconfigure(0,minsize=self.fwidth*2)

    self.right.columnconfigure(0,minsize=self.fwidth*2)

    self.center.columnconfigure(0,minsize=self.fwidth)

    self.tk.after(1000, self.Pinger)
    def Pinger(self):
       #Function to check servers and if its down send email         

       self.tk.after(1000, self.task)

#forever loop
Gui= GUI()
Gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.progress = ttk.Progressbar` seems to be missing `()` i.e. no object is instantiated

Comment: I forgot add comment that I cut code to make it shorter to make faster reading

Comment: @IrenaJodeikiene Unfortunately, removing code in this manner actually makes it harder for us to be able to help you.

Comment: added full code link in description

Comment: "crashes because overload" is extremely vague. What is "overloaded"? What does "crashes" mean -- do you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: Do you know how looks programs when on Windows"not responding" http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZmvxzjXaQiE/VHr0Zo7GjII/AAAAAAAANMs/_s5ww3Z95ls/s1600/screenshot01.png